# Saving parsed json into core data

Tags: json, core-data, swift3, xcode8

so i have successfully parsed JSON data from a web service to show on a table view. On the table view cell, there are 3 labels which are fore the 3 string values and there is also an image which is taken from a separate URL.

So now I want to save this data using core data. I know I can easily save the 3 labels but I wondering how do i go about saving the image URL?

Thank you!

Comment: An URL can be represented by a string. Call `absoluteString` on the URL.

Comment: Okay thank you! Also if you don't mind me asking, the parsed json data on the tableview, how can i save it? because i want to swipe left on the cell and i want it to have a save feature. is that possible and if so, how? thank you!

Comment: It's possible with `UITableViewRowAction`.